# Enumeration problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

An office furniture manufacturer that makes modular storage files offers its customers two choices for the base and four choices for the top, and the modular storage files come in five different heights. The customer may choose any combination of the five different-sized modules so that the finished file has a base, a top, and one, two, three, four, five, or six storage modules.

How many choices does the customer have if the completed file has four storage modules, a top, and a base? The order in which the four modules are stacked is irrelevant.

I know that the answer is 560. But I don't know how I can get there. I'm doing a bit of backwards reasoning because I can't find the missing multiple: 2*4*( ) = 560

Answer (score 0):

For the 4 storage modules you can use the Addition Principle and count the sets of 4 storages in which you have all the 4 storages be different, you have 2 which are the same and the other two are different from them, three which are the same and the third is different  and all four be the same:

0 repeated:  5 different because you can chose 4 of 5 elements in 5 ways  2345, 1345, 1245, 1235, 1234
2 repeated :  5x4x4 /2 = 40 because you can choose in 5 different ways the two elements which will be repeated and the next two elements can be chosen in 4x4 ways  but for chosing the last two different elements choises XY and XX are counted twice so you have to divide in two
3 repeated:  5x4 = 20 because you can chose in 5 ways the three elements which are repeated and in 4 ways the forth which is different
4 repeated:  5  sets with equall elements – 1111, 2222, 3333, 4444 and 5555

So you have  5+40+20+5 = 70